# Can I add yField data in sequence Antd Charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, antd

I would like to add yField data sequentially but unfortunately I'm getting output as you can see in the picture attached but I want to show yField like following:

1. Done
2. Error
3. In Progress
4. Init

[image: current result]

Comment: Can you add more context? What's the shape of the data? What is the value of your `yField`?

Comment: the list on the left side is my yFields like error, ERROR, init and done